# Nested dictionary: sum values of same key of the dictionaries nested as a value of dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to sum values of the same key: `H, C, O, N, S` according to dictionary `composition` for the string input which is a combination of letter `A, C, D, E`.

```
composition = {
    'A':  {'H': 5, 'C': 3, 'O': 1, 'N': 1},
    'C':  {'H': 5, 'C': 3, 'O': 1, 'N': 1, 'S': 1},
    'D':  {'H': 5, 'C': 4, 'O': 3, 'N': 1},
    'E':  {'H': 7, 'C': 5, 'O': 3, 'N': 1},
}

string_input = ['ACDE', 'CCCDA']
```

The expected result should be

```
out = {
    'ACDE' : {'H': 22, 'C': 15, 'O': 8, 'N': 4, 'S': 1},
    'CCCDA' : {'H': 15, 'C': 9, 'O': 3, 'N': 3, 'S': 3},
}
```

I am trying to use `Counter` but stuck at `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Counter'`

```
from collections import Counter

for each in string_input:
  out = sum(Counter(composition[aa]) for aa in each)
```

Comment: How does `'CCCDA` map to `'CCC` in the output?

Comment: You can remove the `(...)` parentheses in the `composition` value definitions, they are entirely redundant.

Comment: you should do this ```out[each] = sum((Counter(composition[aa]) for aa in each), Counter())```

Comment: @MartijnPieters the key, in fact, aren't important but I just want to show what key each composition is calculated from. I will update the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sum()` has a *starting value*, from which it starts the sum. This also provides a default if there are no values to sum in the first argument. That starting value is `0`, an integer.

From the [`sum()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

> `sum(iterable[, start])`
>
> Sums *start* and the items of an *iterable* from left to right and returns the total. *start* defaults to `0`.

When summing `Counter` objects, give it an empty `Counter()` to start off with:

```
sum((Counter(composition[aa]) for aa in each), Counter())
```

If you then assign the result to a *key* in a *dictionary* assigned to `out` you get your expected result as `Counter` instances:

```
>>> out = {}
>>> for each in string_input:
...     out[each] = sum((Counter(composition[aa]) for aa in each), Counter())
...
>>> out
{'ACDE': Counter({'H': 22, 'C': 15, 'O': 8, 'N': 4, 'S': 1}), 'CCCDA': Counter({'H': 25, 'C': 16, 'O': 7, 'N': 5, 'S': 3})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three nested for loops should do the work.

```
out = {}
for x in string_input: # for each string in list
    current = out[x] = {}
    for char in x: # for each character in the string
        cur_composition=composition[char]
        for val in cur_composition: # for all the entry in the composition dictionary for that character
            current[char]= cur_composition[val] if val not in current[char] else cur_composition[val]+current[char]
```