# How to multiply the values of a nested dictionary with different number of keys in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to multiply the values of nested dictionaries that contain a specific string being part of the key. Each nested dictionary has a different number of keys. Here is an example of my inputs:

```
Node = ['AY','AN']

factor =   {'A': {
      ('BY','EY','AY'): 0.95,
      ('BY','EY','AN'): 0.05,
      ('BY','EN','AY'): 0.94,
      ('BY','EN','AN'): 0.06,
      ('BN','EY','AY'): 0.29,
      ('BN','EY','AN'): 0.71,
      ('BN','EN','AY'): 0.001,
      ('BN','EN','AN'): 0.999},
  'J': {
      ('AY','JY'): 0.90,
      ('AN','JY'): 0.05,
  'M': {
      ('AY','MY'): 0.70,
      ('AN','MY'): 0.01}}
```

`Node` contains the strings that must be contained (separately, i.e., first search for keys containing *'AY'* and then for those containing *'AN'*) in each of the keys of the nested dictionaries *'A'*, *'J'* and, *'M'* in `factor`.

**Expected output:**
The output `new_factor` must contain as many keys as elements are in `Node`:

```
new_factor =   { 'AY':{
      ('BY','EY','AY'): 0.95*90*70, # ('BY','EY','AY')*('AY','JY')*('AY','MY')
      ('BY','EN','AY'): 0.94*90*70,
      ('BN','EY','AY'): 0.29*90*70,
      ('BN','EN','AY'): 0.001*90*70}
                 'AN':{
      ('BY','EY','AN'): 0.05*0.05*0.01,
                       # ('BY','EY','AN')*('AN','JY')*('AN','MY')
      ('BY','EN','AN'): 0.06*0.05*0.01,
      ('BN','EY','AN'): 0.71*0.05*0.01,
      ('BN','EN','AN'): 0.999*0.05*0.01}}
```

**Some background:**
I have a piece of code that goes into each of the keys of the nested dictionaries and checks if `st` is contained in the sets that make out the keys.

```
for st in Node:# Each state of not_queried node
    mult = dict()
    for element in factor:
        factor_node = factor[element]
        for state,prob in factor_node.items():
            if(set([st]).issubset(set(state))): # Finds out if st is in key
               mult[state] = prob
```

I also found a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47669562/nested-dictionary-sum-values-of-same-key-of-the-dictionaries-nested-as-a-value). However, this is to add the values instead of multiplying them and I haven't been able to find the transition to find the product.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
Node = ['AY','AN']

factor =   {'A': {
      ('BY','EY','AY'): 0.95,
      ('BY','EY','AN'): 0.05,
      ('BY','EN','AY'): 0.94,
      ('BY','EN','AN'): 0.06,
      ('BN','EY','AY'): 0.29,
      ('BN','EY','AN'): 0.71,
      ('BN','EN','AY'): 0.001,
      ('BN','EN','AN'): 0.999},
  'J': {
      ('AY','JY'): 0.90,
      ('AN','JY'): 0.05},
  'M': {
      ('AY','MY'): 0.70,
      ('AN','MY'): 0.01}
      }

product = 1

for key_1 in factor:
    for key_2, value in factor[key_1].items():
        if Node[0] in key_2 or Node[1] in key_2:
            product *= value

print(product)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @NamanJain, however, your code multiplies also the elements of 'A' among themselves. What I need is that each of the elements in 'A' containing 'AY' is multiplied by the elements that also contain 'AY' in the other two dictionaries ('J' and 'M'). Then, repeat the process for 'AN'